# Integrating Bonobo Git Server with VS 2015 Community Edition

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control

I am using Visual Studio Community Edition (local Development Computer) and I have a Bonobo Git Server setup and running on a separate machine. I am trying to connect through Visual Studio to the server - but somewhere I am failing . VS2015 has local Git - but my Bonobo Git server is on a local instance server with in our domain. How do I point VS2015 Connections to this, I am looking for extensions online but so far I draw blanks and components that work on the local development machine. Please stay on point with the question - I do not want team server I, I do not want github ; I am looking for the answer to my question , not some other service or some other thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how I did it:

1. Create a local Git repo by cloning from your bonobo's Git URL:

[image]

2. Double click the new "local" repo:

[image]

3. Add or create a project or solution in the Repo home page:

[image]

4. Do some work. Make some code. Whatever.
5. Check out your changes by clicking the Changes button in the same Repo home page (Also seen in the previous image)
6. Add a commit message and then Commit All (assuming that's what you want to do) in the Changes screen:

[image]

Might want to note that we're using AD for our Bonobo server and the account running Visual Studio is what is pushing the changes. It's actually a little more friendly than the SharePoint and VS2010 worflow I'm used to, despite being a little weirder to set up.

Comment: ok so far this has to me to what looks like a good point - I made the change to the code file and see it in the changes - I committed , but now that I did this how do I push the entire project that I opened to the remote server ?

Comment: @J Gregg       See my comment above .. so far only issue I have is pushing the entire project to the server

Comment: @J Gregg - I searched and searched but it looked like I needed to exit VS for the git function - I used tortoiseGit and did a diff on the thing. and then followed the screen selection and did a commit and push - that actually did the trick, VS2015 when I did the commit and push only did the changed file .. I guess it did not see the differences ?? I mark your answer as THE ANSWER!!

Comment: @Ken, that'd be my guess that VS didn't know about the changes. Glad to see it worked for you!